# Clone git repo bringing as few commits as possible for merge-base

Tags: git, git-clone

### Scenario

I have a really large repository that takes ~10 minutes to clone.

In a CI job I need to:

- fetch 2 branches.
- compute the merge-base (lowest common ancestor).
- perform a diff between the merge-base commit and one of the branches and some other things based on that diff.

Currently I do a plain `git clone` which, as expected, takes up most of the time.

Is it possible to speed the process by using partial clones?

#### Assumptions:

- one of the branches can be safely assumed to be at most 100 commits away from the merge-base commit.
- the other branch could be further away (thousands of commits) from the merge-base.

#### What I tried

I experimented with a manual partial clone, which seems to yield good results when fetching the branches:

```sh
git init
git remote add origin "repo_url"
git sparse-checkout set "directory_i_am_interested_in"
git fetch origin branch1 --depth 1
git fetch origin branch2 --depth 1
```

This takes ~1 minute in total. The trouble is that `merge-base` fails, because there are just two commits present in my clone, so not enough history to compute.

I figured out I would then `git fetch origin branchx --deepen n` (where I choose `n` based on the assumptions above), to fetch the next `n` commits from each branch until I get a result from `merge-base`.

However, this ends up taking even more time than the simple `git clone`.

Is there something I'm missing here that could be further optimized?
Or is there another way to achieve the same thing more efficiently?

Comment: What about performing a [partial clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone), e.g. with `--filter=blob:none`? This can substantially reduce the time it takes to clone a repository, and unlike limiting things with `--depth` you still have access to the full history.  See also [this github article](https://github.blog/2020-12-21-get-up-to-speed-with-partial-clone-and-shallow-clone/).

Comment: @larsks I've experimented with various combinations, but finally what you suggested brought the biggest improvement.
The optimal strategy was to use a `--filter=blob:none`, and a `sparse-checkout`.